# circular overlay projection distortion

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, kml, google-earth, google-earth-plugin

I’m currently using the ‘GroundOverlay’ function within a KML file to display an circular image.  I know the circle is 48 degrees in diameter, and I want it to look like a circle when I overlay it on the earth.  Rather than being a perfect circle though, it’s distorted, most visibly at the poles.  I think the reason for the distortion is that GoogleEarth assumes my original image used a map projection, so GE “unprojects” my image, creating the distortion.  Is there a way to overlay my circular image as a circle through KML or the maps API by turning off the projection?  Or is my only option to project my circular image into a simple cylindrical projection before I call GroundOverlay on it?  I'd really prefer the first option if it exists.

Comment: You cannot turn off the projection, but you can ignore it by drawing based on pixels rather than lat/lon. That would result in a circle tangent to the surface of the Earth, as opposed to a circle on the surface, (like a skull cap).

Comment: I can't find a use pixels instead of lat/lon option for GroundOverlay.  ScreenOverlay lets you specify a use pixels for units option, but I don't think that's the function I want to use.

Comment: I didn't say that GroundOverlay has such an option. You can draw based on pixels, but you have to code it yourself. (you actually have to do some work!) ;-)